# pointer to a char

Tags: c, string

I have query on how to assign a pointer to a character

Sample program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    const char str1[]="MANCHESTER";
    char *q;
    q=str1;
    *q='A';
    printf("%s\n",q);
}
```

In the the above program, I am assigning a character pointer to string "str1",

When I compile the program with gcc, I get the below warning:

> ptr3.c: In function ‘main’:
>   ptr3.c:7:3: warning: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type

I am not able to understand what the warning means.

Comment: I think you haven't posted the real code you are using. Your error is one line 7 according to the error message. But line 7 is the last line of code! Have you copied and pasted the code accurately into this window?

Comment: There is no such thing as `void main()` in C.

Comment: BTW, it's `int main( void )`, not `void main()`...

Comment: The return type of `main` shall be `int`!

Comment: @Aaron McDaid Maybe he skipped the `# include ...` line?

Comment: [Works for me](http://codepad.org/pvh3F6TI).

Comment: Why not `void main()`?

BTW, It runs on my PC without any warning.

Comment: @FlopCoder because it's not portable, for example. The only types of `main` guaranteed by the standard are `int main(void)` and `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` (up to equivalence, e.g. per typedefs).

Comment: Hi , the full program is:#include <stdio.h>

    void main()
   {
       const char str1[]="MANCHESTER";
       char *q;
       q=str1;
       *q='A';
       printf("%s\n",q);
   }

Comment: @user1150645: next time, please post your actual code. That `const` makes one hell of a difference.

Comment: const in c / c++ is a big topic: http://www.possibility.com/Cpp/const.html

Comment: @Mat I apologize,  i was working 2 sample codes one with const and another without const, got confused with the outputs.

Comment: @FlopCoder On my Fedora 14, the code runs with void main, But yes you are right using of int main(void) is the right syntax.

Answer (score 1):

warnings i get:

```
2: warning: return type of 'main' is not 'int'
: In function 'main':
7: warning: implicit declaration of function 'printf'
7: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'printf'
```

adding include stdio.h and return type int, fixes those.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str1[]="MANCHESTER";
    char *q;
    q=str1;
    *q='A';
    printf("%s\n",q);
    return 0;
}
```

edit:
i guess you should not declare the char array as const, if you plan on modifying it, directly or indirectly through another pointer

Comment: OP mentions that his _real_ code has `const char str1[]=...`.